# Putting a Map in a TableView

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to put a Map inside a table view for a GUI in Javafx.

The map format is `Map<House, String>`.  I require 3 rows.  Where the first row will derive the `house.getName()` as a `String`, `house.getNumber()` as `int` and the last as value from the Map.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Three rows, or three columns? If you really mean three rows, are you wanting a column for every entry in the map?

Answer (score -1):

It's very simple if you use map and set interface.Add all the House object in the key and String as value. convert all the key value using ***map.keySet()***.
I will add a piece a code that may help you

```
*your pojo class*

public class House
{
  private String name;
  private int number;

  public House(String name, int number)
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number;
  }
//create getters and setters
}
```

Use the map for adding all the object as key and its value in string format

```
    Map<House, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    House house1 = new House("name1", 10);
    House house2 = new House("name2", 20);

    map.put(house1, "value1");
    map.put(house2, "value2");

    Set<House> houses = map.keySet();
    for (House house : houses)
    {
        System.out.print("Name: " + house.getName());
        System.out.print(",Number: " + house.getNumber());
        System.out.println(",Value: " + map.get(house));
    }
```

Sample output:

```
Name: name1 ,Number: 10 ,Value: value1
Name: name2 ,Number: 20 ,Value: value2
```

Add the abovecode in the place where you have to display as table...

Comment: The question is asking how to configure a `TableView` to display these data. This doesn't answer the question.